# convergence of square summable sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I have seen a very interensting but for me confusing statement.

It says that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} < \infty,$
then necessarily holds that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0$ (from neccesary condition of convergence of sequence). But i don't understand, how is connected mentioned condition and convergence of squared summable sequence?

I mean i know, that if the series of the sequence $a_{n}$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0,$ but does it hold for the mentioned statement as well?

Comment: $a_n^2\to 0 \implies a_n\to 0$

Comment: In the statement that you know, first replace $a_n$ by $a_n^2$ since that's what you are given. What does this help you conclude? From here, it is an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument that I encourage you to try yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially asking if the following implication holds:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}{a_n}^2=0\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0,$$
which is true, since the square root is a continuous map at $0$.

Comment: Thanks very much, of course, i totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

You know

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n < \infty$$
$$\to \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n=0$$

Choose $b_n = a_{n}^{2} $. Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} < \infty$$
$$\to \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}^{2}=0$$
$$\to (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n})^{2}=0 \tag{You know why right?}$$
$$\to \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0$$